# occur error while debug linux source code : Exception occured while copying sources to remote machine

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

> environment : Windows 10; Viusal Studio 2017; VMWare 14.0; Ubuntu 18.04
>
> Occur error :  Exception occured while copying sources to remote machine

[image: setting]

Here is my debug result:

```
1>------ 已启动生成: 项目: Ubuntu Program, 配置: Debug x64 ------
1>Validating sources
1>Copying sources remotely to '192.168.27.128'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(157,5): error : Exception occured while copying sources to remote machine - 路径中具有非法字符。
1>已完成生成项目“Ubuntu Program.vcxproj”的操作 - fail。
```

And my source code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    printf("hello from Ubuntu_Program!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have read the Microsoft Docs and search on the Google but don't know why and how to figure it out, I will be pleasure if someone can help me.

Comment: Perhaps there's something off with directory structure? https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2383

Comment: For any future readers, the error message says there are illegal symbols in the path.

Comment: Thanks， I've solved it! I remove the space in my project name, casue it makes an error in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the space in your project name will solve this problem. Replace it with underline _ if you want.